# How do I stream output (one line at a time) from `subprocess`?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm really struggling to successfully stream output from a bash command in my Python script using the `subprocess` package. The command is just a simple `AWS CLI` command to upload an object to S3:

```
aws s3 cp --profile MY-PROFILE UPLOADED_FILE s3://BUCKET/PREFIX/
```

When I run this in `bash`, it shows the progress of the upload. With `subprocess`, I can only get it working in the following ways:

- Final output only  at the end.

  ```
  upload: ./OBJECT to s3://BUCKET/PREFIX/OBJECT
  ```
- Line by line output

  ```
  Completed 512.0 KiB/12.2 MiB (697.8 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining

  Completed 768.0 KiB/12.2 MiB (980.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining

  Completed 1.0 MiB/12.2 MiB (1.2 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining    

  Completed 1.2 MiB/12.2 MiB (1.5 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining    

  Completed 1.5 MiB/12.2 MiB (1.6 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining    

  Completed 1.8 MiB/12.2 MiB (1.4 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
  ```
- Similar thing without line separation:

  ```
  b'Completed 256.0 KiB/12.2 MiB (297.5 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining\rCompleted 512.0 KiB/12.2 MiB (506.7 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining\rCompleted 768.0 KiB/12.2 MiB (544.4 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining\rCompleted 1.0 MiB/12.2 MiB (672.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 1.2 MiB/12.2 MiB (707.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 1.5 MiB/12.2 MiB (780.3 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 1.8 MiB/12.2 MiB (849.1 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 2.0 MiB/12.2 MiB (865.6 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 2.2 MiB/12.2 MiB (971.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 2.5 MiB/12.2 MiB (992.4 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining  \rCompleted 2.8 MiB/12.2 MiB (1.0 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
  ```

What I need is to just use one line and show the live status, just as it would do in bash.

Here are a number of different functions I've tried, all with no luck:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess
import os
import shlex
from time import sleep


def stream_process(process):
    go = process.poll() is None
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line)
    return go

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while stream_process(process):
    sleep(0.1)


def run(command):
  with subprocess.Popen(command, text=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
      print(line)

run(command)

process = Popen(command, text=True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll() is not None and output == b'':
        break
    if output:
        print (output.strip())
retval = process.poll()


with Popen(command, text=True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:

    while True: 
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        print(line.strip())


    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line.strip(), "\n", flush=True, end='')
        # print(line.strip())


print(result.stdout.readlines())

print("args", result.args)
print("returncode", result.returncode)
print("stdout", result.stdout)
print("stderr", result.stderr)
print("check_returncode()", result.check_returncode())

def run_command(cmd):
    p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    return p.poll()

run_command(command)
# invoke process
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Poll process.stdout to show stdout live
while True:
  output = process.stdout.readline()
  if process.poll() is not None:
    break
  if output:
    print(output.strip())
rc = process.poll()


print(result.stdout.readlines())
while True:
    line = result.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line, flush=True)
```

**FAQ**

> Why don't you use `boto3` instead of `subprocess` + `bash`?

I'm developing a program for non-Python devs, so I'd like to limit dependencies and only use standard packages as much as possible.

Comment: Pretty sure tags `bash` and `shell` does not have anything to do with this. I might be wrong, but as far as I can tell it does not have anything to do with it. Because you can do this with various shells like `zsh`. Might try removing?

Answer (score 1):

You simply should to:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(("ls"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line.decode("utf-8").rstrip())
p.wait()
status = p.poll()
print("process terminate with code: %s" % status)
```

Result in:

```
my-file.txt
...
process terminate with code: 0
```

When the subprocess exit, stdout is closed, which break the loop.

subprocess stdout is a bytes stream. If you need str objects, you should decode it: `line.decode("utf-8")`.

But I think this is not the problem. Some command have different output in case of stdout is a terminal or a pipe. Like with `wget`.
I you want a progress bar, you have to parse output and implement your own progress bar.

Comment: I have to add the `shell=True` parameter to `Popen`, otherwise I always get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "command"`   

After adding it, the output still does not stream.

Comment: I don't known about `awsv`, so I replace with simple command in order to illustrate how to capture line by line output. I think you are able to replace by your own command.

Answer (score 0):

`for line in process.stdout` and `process.stdout.readline()` are not fit for the task because they don't return before a whole line has ended, i. e. a `\n` is received, while a progress part only ends with `\r`. A way to read output independently of any line termination is to use [os.read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.read):

```
from os         import read

process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE)
while buffer := read(process.stdout.fileno(), 4096):
    print(buffer.decode(), end='')
```

As xrisk noted, using `text=True` would allow lines ending with `\r` to be read with `readline()`, but that's of no use here because therewith [*all line endings in the output will be converted to `'\n'`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

But there's indeed a way to use a text stream without loosing the original line endings by means of [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) - therewith we can do this:

```
import io

process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE)
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, newline=""): print(line, end="")
```

Comment: But the thing is they don't work as required (~25-30 lines instead of 3 lines). Right now, it's printing the streaming output in a new line. I'd like it to print by updating the same line - just as it does on the terminal...

Comment: Now I understand the problem; I revised the answer.

Comment: Since you are decoding the buffer, you might as well use `universal_newlines=True` and open the stdout pipe in text mode, avoiding the need for buffering.

Comment: Text mode is not usable here, since therewith _all line endings in the output will be converted to `'\n'`_, and the _need is to just use one line and show the live status_, for which the `\r` characters have to be kept.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion shortly. In the meantime, is there any solution without requiring the `os` package?

Comment: Your request made me have another look into this, and indeed there's another solution.

Comment: I'd like to use return (as it will be part of a function) rather than print. Seems that this would be somewhat complicated (with the `end` parameter)?

Comment: Not at all would it be complicated - the `end=""` just serves to print the line as it is without adding an unwanted newline. If you don't use `print` in the first place there's nothing which could add anything unwanted.

Comment: So when I use it as a standalone function, the print works fine. But when it's part of a larger class, nothing gets printed when the function is called. I also can't use return instead of print - I get error "Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"

Comment: Of course nothing gets printed if you don't use `print`. And of course you can't simply use  `return` instead of `print` - `return` breaks out of the loop, you know. Perhaps you want `yield line`.

Comment: I do use print within the function but when it's called as part of a class, no output is rendered.

Comment: You may want to post this different problem as a new question.